# Mustache JS using $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

Hi I am using Mustache JS to fetch the data using JSON. my template is below.

```
                <script id="patientTabl" type="text/template">
            <table class="bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Patient Id</th>
            <th>SSN</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {{#patients}}
            <tr>

            <td data-title="First Name">{{firstName}}<div href="#" class="tool-tip">

            <span class="right-arrow">
            <img class="callout" src="images/callout.gif" />
            <ul>
            <li><a href="update-patient.html?id={{id}}">View/Update Patient</a></li>
            <li><a href="JavaScript:getInsurPlans()" id="viewInsurPlans">View Insurance Plans</a></li>
            <li><a href="patient-admission.html?id={{id}}">Create Patient Admission</a></li>
            </ul>

            </span>
            </td>
            <td data-title="Last Name">{{lastName}}</td>
            <td data-title="Phone Number">&nbsp;{{phones}}</td>
            <td data-title="Patient Id">{{id}}</td>
            <td data-title="SSN">{{ssn}}</td>

            </tr>
            {{/patients}}
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </script>
```

for this I am writing below jquery code to fetch the data into template. I am getting response but data is not inserting into template. Please help

```
            $.getJSON('/ePhase-web/patients', function (data) {


            var template = $('#patientTabl').html();
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

            $('#sampleArea').html(html);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly is going wrong. I don't see any obvious mistakes. So a generic debugging is in order.

Most browsers have some sort of network tab. Does it show the request being made? is the request succeeding? You method will only be called if the request succeeds.

If the request succeeds you can debug the code itself. With a development console open you can place the word debugger were you'd like execution to pause so you can inspect the value of variables (by hovering over them with your mouse)

Does the jquery selection of patientTab give the right element as a result?

What does "data" look like? Is an error thrown when the mustache.to_html is called? what does the html look like?

Does $("#sampleArea") find any elements?

I think going over these questions one by one will point you towards fixing the bug or asking a more solvable answer. See also [this article on debugging in chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jauco. I guess problem is with array of objects. You have any idea how to fetch array of objects?

Comment: Do you mean that "data" contains an array an that you want a patienttable for each item in the array?

Comment: I am able to fetch when there is single object but when like below I am not able to fetch [{ 
  "menu": "File", 
 
},{ 
  "menu": "File1", 
 
}]

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what fetch means. I also don't know where that array fits in your code. Could you rephrase the quastion using the variable and method names from your code sample? (E.g. The getjson fails when the data retrieved is an array)

Comment: Please look into sample code from the below URL                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789103/getjson-not-able-to-append-the-array-objects-to-html