# $.getjson not able to append the array objects to html

Tags: javascript, json

Hi my json data is like below

```
[{
    "menu": "File",
}, {
    "menu": "File1",
}]
```

I have written jquery code to append the response to html like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {

        var template = $('#personTpl').html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#sampleArea').html(html);
    });

});
```

Mustache template is below :

```
<script id="personTpl" type="text/template">
    <h1>{{menu}}</h1>
</script>
```

Please help

Comment: Your JSON syntax is invalid. Check against http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: thanks, I have changed my json but response is not appending.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your JSON:

```
[
  {
     "menu": "File"
  },
  {
     "menu": "File1"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks, I have changed my json but response is not appending.

Answer (score 0):

Your template should iterate through the JSON:

```
<script id="personTpl" type="text/template">
 {{#data}}
   <h1>{{menu}}</h1>
 {{/data}}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I found solution like <script id="personTpl" type="text/template">
{{ #. }}<h1>{{menu}}</h1>  {{ /. }}

</script>